# Sql. Use like with In operand

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using sql server 2005.
I'm trying to search people with few possible names.
something like this:

```
select PersonID from Person 
where Name like + '%' (select [value] dbo.fnSplit('David;John;Kevin', ';')) + '%'
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Because that's invalid syntax, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select PersonID from Person p inner join
(select value as AName from dbo.fnSplit('David;John;Kevin', ';')) Names
on p.Name LIKE '%' + Names.Value + '%'
```

That should allow you to use the LIKE as you specified.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `like` with multiple patterns, but you can change your select to use one pattern at a time:

```
select PersonID
from Person p
where exists ( select 1 from (
        select [value] as name
        from dbo.fnSplit('David;John;Kevin', ';')
    ) n
    where p.Name like '%'+n.name+'%'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to split the names and compare by them, try:

```
SELECT PersonID FROM Person 
WHERE Name IN (select [value] FROM dbo.fnSplit('David;John;Kevin', ';'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select PersonID from Person where Name like + '%David%'
union
select PersonID from Person where Name like + '%John%'
union
select PersonID from Person where Name like + '%Kevin%';
```

Comment: Indeed, my bad. But, I'll leave it to complete other answers :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this, why are you using fnSplit:

```
select PersonID from Person where Name like '%David%'or Name like + '%John%'
or Name like + '%Kevin%'
```

Comment: yes, but what if fnSplit returns 50 names? I don't want to limit it to 3 names.